# Remove margins from a matplotlib figure

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'd like to plot a NumPy array using `imshow` in `matplotlib` and save it as a JPEG image. However, I can't manage to remove margins/paddings/borders from the image.

My code:

```
plt.imshow(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)) ;
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('test.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, facecolor='black')
```

I've followed all recommendations that I could find here on Stackoverflow but none of them would help removing uneven white borders (I made them black in this figure) seen below:

[image]

Comment: did answer #1 solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing white space around a saved image in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image-in-matplotlib/27227718

Answer (score 0):

As it was described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26610602/265289, it's important to also call:

```
fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

alongside `pad_inches=0`. This removes the extra space to the left and bottom of the image.

Answer (score -1):

setting pad_inches = -1 solved this for me (saving as png).

I suspect the pad_inches=0 was being interpreted as "falsey" and ignored

Comment: Unfortunately this removes parts of the image as well.