# ax.fill() in matplotlib creates white margins

Tags: image, matplotlib, plot, resize, caffe

I'm working on image segmentation using caffe, sciki-image, opencv and matplotlib/pyplot. This work involves some image resizing. Essentially, after I've loaded and resized the image:

```
put_image = caffe.io.load_image(os.path.join(source_dir, pix)
input_image = caffe.io.resize_image(input_image, (600,500), interp_order=3)
```

I do quite a bit of processing. Everything worked well until I decided to add some contours to the image:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(image2)
...
ax.fill(vald[:, 0], vald[:, 1], fill=False, color='red', linewidth=1)
```

where `vald` is some array and `image2` is some output from processed `input_image`

After saving it

```
fig.savefig(save_dir + str(idx) + ".png", bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

I get something like this, which is essentially a cropped version of the original image

[image]

So of course my first reaction was to just crop the image and resize it afterwards, but it turned out to lose much of its quality (resolution deteriorated). I tried following suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image-in-matplotlib), but didn't get any improvement either.

Comment: Looks like the axis limits have changed.  I guess it is putting the image at (0,0) spanning up to (500, 600), but it is actually putting the starting at -100 instead of 0.  Try to enforce the `ax.set_xlim([0, 500])` and `ax.set_ylim([0, 600])` (maybe ylim should be 600, 0 due to the inverted y-scale...?)

Comment: nice suggestion, but why does the image get rotated?

Comment: ok fixed it, many thanks!

Comment: Great!  I post it as an answer to make the question show up as solved.  Please accept it if it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow-up on my comment:
The axis limits have changed. The image is in the rectangle between (0,0) and (500, 600).  However the x- and y-lim are not exactly that; they range from (-100, -100) up to (500, 600). Just update the limits with `ax.set_xlim([0, 500])` and `ax.set_ylim([600, 0])` to remove the white frame around.

Note: if you also want to hide the ticks you easily do this with `ax.set_xticks([])` and `ax.set_yticks([])`, or by setting the visibility of the ticks to `False`.

Comment: yeah, on the second thought it is the most obvious thing ever)