# Store calculated filter banks into spectrogram image with Python

Tags: python, numpy, signals, figure

I am using the [following code](https://haythamfayek.com/2016/04/21/speech-processing-for-machine-learning.html) to calculate the frequency or the MFCC coefficients of a wavelet signal. When I have calculated my signals (frequency over time) in 2D numpy arrays I am trying to store it locally into a .png images. I am trying to do so with two different possible ways. Firstly, by using:

```
matplotlib.image.imsave("my_img.png", filter_banks)
```

That leads to:

[image]

and the second way using librosa tool:

```
import librosa.display
from matplotlib import cm
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(..., ...), dpi=1)
librosa.display.specshow(filter_banks.T, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("_plot_static_conv.png")
plt.show()
```

and the result is look like:

[image]

My issue is that I am having some white margin over the image which are not desired. How can I have the same size also in the second case and avoid the white margin over the image that I guess is caused by the plt.figure?

**EDIT:** I tried to use the answer from the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image-in-matplotlib) but it did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

probably as a workaround, your white margin is 4 pixel,
could you save your second image with 8 more pixel in height and width.

then crop it using c2v

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.png")
crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

as proposed in: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15589825/4610938

Comment: I am not sure it is really good work around to store and crop the image. I guess there is a solution that i can save it already cropped.

Comment: I have found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295367/4610938 an answer where the figure white padding is removed, hope it'll help