# Setting border spacing matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

I want to have a matplotlib figure without ANY padding. Currently I do this manually via the IPython (Spyder3) interactive window and its configure subplots window. As shown in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL73q.png).

I need to automate this process and decided to have a look at the Tight layout options.

```
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, 1])
```

This does not result in the intended result as some margins do still remain. As shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddMU4.png).

How do I force figures to have no padding at all. I expect the setting to exist as I'm able to change it in the GUI of IPython.

Comment: Can you try `plt.margins(0,0)`?

Comment: In particular, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310715/4124317).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI option you're using can be coded with the `plt.subplots_adjust` command. Something like `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)` should achieve what you want

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Please consider marking this answer as accepted.