# Matplotlib: remove white border from edge of saved image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to use matplotlib to create a 2D density plot of a distribution to use as a heightmap. Here's what I've got:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import kde
import numpy as np

# make fake data
data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[1, 0.5], [0.5, 3]], 200)
x, y = data.T

# kde
nbins = 100
k = kde.gaussian_kde(data.T)
xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():nbins*1j, y.min():y.max():nbins*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(5,5))
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), shading='gouraud', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('heightmap.png', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

This produces the following image (the data is random each run of course):

[image]

If you download that image file or change the CSS of the stackoverflow page background, you'll see that image has a little white border surrounding it. I thought I could use a hack to remove that white border by changing the background color to a fixed color with `fig.patch.set_facecolor('orange')` but that doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I can do to remove the white border from the edge of the saved image? I'd be grateful for any insights others can offer!

Comment: Do *not* use `tight_layout` or `bbox_inches = 'tight'`. Instead set the margins off yourself, e.g. via `fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)`.

Comment: nailed it! If you make that an answer I shall bring unto it frank incense and acceptance

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310715/4124317) to a very popular question tells us. So I would rather close this as duplicate.

Comment: Ah excellent. There were many questions with related titles but this wasn't one of the first