# Matplotlib: Remove unused border area from the saved image file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing shapes using matplotlib, like that

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

ax.tick_params(
    axis  = 'both',
    which = 'both',
    bottom = False,
    top    = False,
    left   = False,
    right  = False,
    labelbottom = False,
    labelleft   = False
    )

ax.patch.set_facecolor('#FFFF99')
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((0.1, 0.1), 0.3, 0.2,
                     facecolor = "green", edgecolor = "black"))
ax.add_patch(patches.Circle((0.5, 0.5), radius = 0.05, facecolor="blue"))

fig.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

What I get is

[image]

The shapes are good, but there is white border outside of the region where I draw shapes; it is not seen on the white background, but it is there.

The question is: How to get rid of this white outer border in the saved file? `bbox_inches='tight'` does not help.

---

PS: `fig.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)` does the job. Unfortunately it is sort of "too tight", because now I lost bottom and right parts of the axes frame,

[image]

Probably matplotlib bug (I am using version 3.1.3)

Comment: Can you try `fig.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)` and see if it works.

Comment: `transparent=True` makes the outer border transparent; unfortunately, it also makes transparent my background which I created by `ax.patch.set_facecolor('#FFFF99')`

Comment: Have you tried a `plt.tight_layout()` call before saving the figure. See also the [Matplotlib tight layout guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html).

Comment: Did you try this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image-in-matplotlib)

Comment: `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1)`

Comment: Yep, `fig.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)` works. Thanks!