# How to remove margins padding around grouped matplotlib edges of the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a grid of `matplotlib` subplots with no borders or whitespace around the edges of the figure (0 margin). I have tried various suggestions like `plt.tight_layout()`, `fig.subplots_adjust()`, and manually setting `fig.set_size_inches()`, and also `frameon=False`, but I still have some whitespace padding around the borders as shown in the image below.

[image]

Here is the code to reproduce it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rows, columns = 4, 3
images = [np.random.rand(4, 4) for i in range(rows * columns)]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, columns, figsize=(columns, rows))
axs = axs.flatten()

# Display each image on its respective subplot
for img, ax in zip(images, axs):
    ax.matshow(img)
    ax.axis('off')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.02, hspace=0.02)
plt.show()
```

Any suggestions on how to completely remove the whitespace and margins around the grid would be appreciated. I would like the subplots to be packed tightly together.

Comment: Just saw this was in the Reopen queue. However, the answer posted by the OP is the same is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57498238/7758804) in the duplicate, as such, this question should remain closed.

Answer (score -1):

Solved by adding this: `plt.tight_layout(pad=0)`.

`pad=0` Is the part I was missing. It seems that the default pad is `1.08`.