# Shadow effect when saving a figure with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a "simple" height map (64px x 64px) with matplotlib, but when I save the figure it creates a "border" with a "white shadow" in my plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = 0.5*np.ones((100,100))
X,Y = np.linspace(1,100,100),np.linspace(1,100,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,np.linspace(0,max(abs(X)),100))  

px = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']  # pixel in inches
res_v = 64 #vertical resolution in pixels
res_h = 64 #horizontal resolution in pixels


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(res_h*px, res_v*px))
ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,data, cmap='Greys',shading='gouraud',vmax=1,vmin=0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("gradient.png", bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)
```

Plot with a white border:

[image: Plot with a white border]

you can download the original figure and zoom in to see the white border.

Plot with zoom:

[image: Plot with zoom]

How can I remove it?

I've already tried changing the shading.

Comment: Did you check out [Removing white space around a saved image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image)? Does one of the solutions work for you?

Comment: I don't see a white border on the original plot.  Could this be something to do with your image viewer?  How did you make the zoomed plot?